# How to get checkbox with hierarchy filtering in Spotfire to work?

Tags: filtering, hierarchy, spotfire

I am trying to insert a hierarchy filter in spotfire as shown in http://stn.spotfire.com/spotfire_client_help/filter/filter_what_is_hierarchy_filter.htm.

**Region      District**
Region 1   District 1
Region 1   District 2
Region 2   District 1
Region 2   District 2

I am brand new to spotfire, so any help is apprecaited on how to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were almost there. at the bottom of the page you linked is the documentation to [create a hierarchy filter](http://stn.spotfire.com/spotfire_client_help/filter/filter_creating_a_hierarchy_filter.htm).

go to Insert » Hierarchy... and add your columns in order you like (in this case, you should use Region, then District).